# RenderScript No JNI_OnLoad found error

Tags: android, crash, renderscript

I am using renderscript library in my project and I perfectly run my apk on Samsung S4 I9500. But when I tried this in other phones I get crash.

```
No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libRSSupport.so 0x4185f0f0, skipping init
02-23 19:42:40.370    8994-8994/com.example.gameboy.gununtesti E/dalvikvm﹕ ERROR: couldn't find native method
02-23 19:42:40.370    8994-8994/com.example.gameboy.gununtesti E/dalvikvm﹕ Requested: Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;._nInit:()V
02-23 19:42:40.370    8994-8994/com.example.gameboy.gununtesti E/JNIHelp﹕ RegisterNatives failed for 'android/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript', aborting
02-23 19:42:40.370    8994-8994/com.example.gameboy.gununtesti A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 8994
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post `libRSSupport.c` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include libRSSupport.so + the other native libraries in your .apk. This is attempting to load the system version of the compatibility, library, which will not work with your app.

Comment: How to do that exactly? Can you help me, I'm new to renderscript. I did move libRSSupport to libraries and include it but nothing changed. Also what you mean about other native libraries? Thanks :)

Comment: And also, this works perfectly in my Samsung galaxy s4 but fails in other phones. If I didn't include those libraries how can s4 run this application?

Comment: The s4 is running it on the actual driver, rather than relying on the fallback mechanism that is the .so libraries. You need to bundle every .so produced for your various .rs files. There should be one .so for each .rs file (per architecture).

Comment: @Stephen Hines According to official documentation the setup is really easy, it doesn't mention the need to include above mentioned libraries at all? [Using the RenderScript Support Library APIs][1]. Also, how is this working in Muzei App? It seems to use support Render Script and I can't see them including these libraries either.


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#ide-setup

Comment: Muzei only uses intrinsics, so there are no custom scripts that it needs to include (i.e. everything lives in libRSSupport.so, although Muzei might not even be using the compatibility library, in which case it needs to bundle nothing). Android Studio should be automatically bundling the .so files for use of the compatibility library, but perhaps there is a bug there.

Comment: Muzei is using support Render Script and e.g. ScriptIntrinsicBlur in ImageBlurrer, when I try to do the same I get "android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading libRSSupport library". Should I make a bug to Android Studio?    [1]: https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/blob/master/android-client-common/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/muzei/util/ImageBlurrer.java

Comment: Feel free to file a bug against Android Studio, but I do think that this is a packaging issue for your apk. You need to include the appropriate .so files, and they are clearly missing for the architecture you are trying to run on. That is why it continues to try to use the /system/lib/... version instead of one that got installed to your app's directory.